# How to hide menu on fragment (which is being replaced from the layout)?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-menu

I have checked and tried out all the possible codes here but those didn't work for me as i am replacing the layout only not having different toolbar.I am using `fragments` and `NavigationDrawer`, the `navigationdrawer` has `listview`,  when a listitem is clicked it is replacing the layout with the following fragments. But how do i hide the `menu` or modify it based on different layout appeard?

Comment: Just need `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to control the option menu from `Fragment` you need to call [setHasOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) in the `onCreate` of the `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Then you can add, remove or clear the menu overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu`. For example this code remove every item in options menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it works for me, u can try this code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }



 @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.overflow).setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: This is the solution that actually worked. I looped through the menu items and hid anything undesirable for the current fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide the code of the things that you tried, it is difficult to say what might work.

I worked in an app that also had a `NavigationDrawer` and for me, what made the difference was to call `menu.clear()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` of each fragment.

A sample code would look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    if (!mNavigationDrawerIsOpened) {
        // Clear the menu from menuitems added from other fragments
        menu.clear();

        // Inflate your new menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.new_fragment, menu);

        // get the menu items of that new menu
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_traffic_spinner);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not planning to hide it on navigation drawer open kindly check my question

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding you, but if what bothers you is the `if`, just remove it. It was an `if` that I had because I do not want to show the MenuItems when the Drawer is open. It is the recommended behavior for the NavigationDrawer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `setHasOptionsMenu()` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is now deprecated, you can do this also with the following:

For example in the `onCreateView()`-method you could remove your menu item with:

```
requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
    @Override
    public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menu.removeItem(R.id.menuItemToRemove);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        return false; //report no menu selection handled
    }
});
```

And in the `onStop()`-method you could add it again with:

```
requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
    @Override
    public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        return false; //report no menu selection handled
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**setHasOptionsMenu()** and **onCreateOptionsMenu()** is now deprecated, you can do this also with the following:

```
requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_reporte,menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch(menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.menu.menu_reporte:

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    },getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
```